# next category page 404 wordpress custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination, custom-post-type

Im making a my own post type (custom post type) and I have a error, when Im switching a page. For example, when I open a category, it shows a posts, but when I go to other page, for example, second, it shows a 404(not found) error.

Page without error - www*****/category/cat-name/
Page WITH error - www*****/category/cat-name/page/2

This is my *taxonomy-portfolio_categories.php* file

```
<div class="container page min-height">
    <div class="row works infinite-container">
        <div class="col-md-12 category-menu">
        <?php
            $taxonomy = 'portfolio_categories';
            $cat = get_the_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy);  
            foreach ( $cat as $cat_slug){$category_slug = $cat_slug->slug;}
            $terms = get_terms($taxonomy);
                if ( $terms && !is_wp_error( $terms ) ) :
            ?>

            <script>
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    var categoryClass = '<?php echo $category_slug ?>';
                    $('.'+categoryClass).addClass('current');
                });
            </script>

                <ul>
                    <?php foreach ( $terms as $term ) { ?>
                        <li class="<?php echo $term->slug; ?>"><a href="<?php echo get_term_link($term->slug, $taxonomy); ?>"><?php echo $term->name; ?></a></li>
                    <?php } ?>
                </ul>
            <?php endif;?>
        </div>

        <?php           
            $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'portfolio',
                'taxonomy'  => $taxonomy,
                'posts_per_page' => 2,
                'portfolio_categories' => $category_slug,
                'paged' => $paged
            );
            $temp = $wp_query; $wp_query= null;

            $wp_query = new WP_Query($args); 
            while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); 
            $category = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'portfolio_categories');
        ?>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 work">
                <div class="placeholder">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="work-link"></a>
                    <div class="work-overlay">
                        <div class="overlay-content">
                            <div class="category-name"><?php foreach ( $category as $cat){echo $cat->name;}?></div>
                            <div class="work-title"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="work-thumb">
                        <div style="background-image:url('<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) ); ?>')"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php 
        endwhile; 
            if(have_posts() == NULL){
                echo info("Sorry, but there is no content available at this time!");
            }
        ?>

        <?php
            if (function_exists('custom_pagination')) {
                custom_pagination($wp_query->max_num_pages,"",$paged);
            }
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

There's my PHP for taxonomy and `register_post_type`

```
function create_portfolio_taxonomies() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'              => _x( 'Portfolio Categories', 'taxonomy general name' ),
        'singular_name'     => _x( 'Category', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
        'search_items'      => __( 'Search Categories' ),
        'all_items'         => __( 'All Categories' ),
        'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Category' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Category:' ),
        'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Category' ),
        'update_item'       => __( 'Update Category' ),
        'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Category' ),
        'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Category Name' ),
        'menu_name'         => __( 'Categories' ),
    );

    $args = array(
        'hierarchical'      => true, // Set this to 'false' for non-hierarchical taxonomy (like tags)
        'labels'            => $labels,
        'show_ui'           => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var'         => true,
        'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => 'cat', 'with_front' => false ),
    );

    register_taxonomy( 'portfolio_categories', array( 'portfolio' ), $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_portfolio_taxonomies', 0 );

function cptui_register_my_cpts_portfolio() {

    /**
     * Post Type: Portfolio.
     */

    $labels = array(
        "name" => __( "Portfolio", "" ),
        "singular_name" => __( "portfolio", "" ),
        "menu_name" => __( "Portfolio", "" ),
        "all_items" => __( "All portfolios", "" ),
        "edit_item" => __( "Edit", "" ),
        "view_item" => __( "View", "" ),
        "view_items" => __( "View portfolio", "" ),
        "not_found" => __( "Portfolio not found", "" ),
    );

    $args = array(
        "label" => __( "Portfolio", "" ),
        "labels" => $labels,
        "description" => "portfolio page",
        "public" => true,
        "publicly_queryable" => true,
        "show_ui" => true,
        "show_in_rest" => false,
        "rest_base" => "",
        "has_archive" => 'portfolio',
        "show_in_menu" => true,
        "exclude_from_search" => false,
        "capability_type" => "post",
        "map_meta_cap" => true,
        "hierarchical" => false,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'cat', 'with_front' => false ),
        "query_var" => true,
        "supports" => array( "title", "editor", "thumbnail", "excerpt", "custom-fields", "multi-post-image" ),
        "taxonomies" => array( "portfolio_categories" ),
    );

    register_post_type( "portfolio", $args );
}

add_action( 'init', 'cptui_register_my_cpts_portfolio' );
```

Pagination function

```
function custom_pagination($numpages = '', $pagerange = '', $paged='') {

  if (empty($pagerange)) {
    $pagerange = 5;
  }

  global $paged;
  if (empty($paged)) {
    $paged = 1;
  }
  if ($numpages == '') {
    global $wp_query;
    $numpages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
    if(!$numpages) {
        $numpages = 1;
    }
  }

  $pagination_args = array(
    'base'            => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
    'format'          => 'page/%#%',
    'total'           => $numpages,
    'current'         => $paged,
    'show_all'        => False,
    'end_size'        => 1,
    'mid_size'        => $pagerange,
    'prev_next'       => True,
    'prev_text'       => __('&laquo;'),
    'next_text'       => __('&raquo;'),
    'type'            => 'plain',
    'add_args'        => false,
    'add_fragment'    => ''
  );

  $paginate_links = paginate_links($pagination_args);

  if ($paginate_links) {
    echo "<nav class='pagination'>";
      echo $paginate_links;
    echo "</nav>";
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you set `with_front => false` to `with_front => true`?

Comment: @justkidding96 same error

Comment: `/category/cat-name/page/2` what does this mean? Does this refer to a second page?

Comment: @justkidding96 yes it is.

Comment: And what for setting do you have by the permalinks?

Comment: @justkidding96 "Post name" ,for example for default posts all working very well, but for custom post type not

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `slug => 'category'` from the rewrite option and it should be work.

Comment: thats not a issue

Comment: im updated my post with taxonomy-portfolio_categories.php

Answer (score 0):

This code is working for me perfectly. If you have still issue then try to change permalink settings to "Post Name".

```
function create_portfolio_taxonomies() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'              => _x( 'Portfolio Categories', 'taxonomy general name' ),
        'singular_name'     => _x( 'Category', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
        'search_items'      => __( 'Search Categories' ),
        'all_items'         => __( 'All Categories' ),
        'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Category' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Category:' ),
        'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Category' ),
        'update_item'       => __( 'Update Category' ),
        'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Category' ),
        'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Category Name' ),
        'menu_name'         => __( 'Categories' ),
    );

    $args = array(
        'hierarchical'      => true, // Set this to 'false' for non-hierarchical taxonomy (like tags)
        'labels'            => $labels,
        'show_ui'           => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var'         => true,
        'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => 'portfolio-category', 'with_front' => false ),
    );

    register_taxonomy( 'portfolio_categories', array( 'portfolio' ), $args );
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_portfolio_taxonomies', 0 );

function cptui_register_my_cpts_portfolio() {

    /**
     * Post Type: Portfolio.
     */

    $labels = array(
        "name" => __( "Portfolio", "" ),
        "singular_name" => __( "portfolio", "" ),
        "menu_name" => __( "Portfolio", "" ),
        "all_items" => __( "All portfolios", "" ),
        "edit_item" => __( "Edit", "" ),
        "view_item" => __( "View", "" ),
        "view_items" => __( "View portfolio", "" ),
        "not_found" => __( "Portfolio not found", "" ),
    );

    $args = array(
        "label" => __( "Portfolio", "" ),
        "labels" => $labels,
        "description" => "portfolio page",
        "public" => true,
        "publicly_queryable" => true,
        "show_ui" => true,
        "show_in_rest" => false,
        "rest_base" => "",
        "has_archive" => 'portfolio',
        "show_in_menu" => true,
        "exclude_from_search" => false,
        "capability_type" => "post",
        "map_meta_cap" => true,
        "hierarchical" => false,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'portfolio', 'with_front' => false ),
        "query_var" => true,
        "supports" => array( "title", "editor", "thumbnail", "excerpt", "custom-fields", "multi-post-image" ),
        "taxonomies" => array( "portfolio_categories" ),
    );

    register_post_type( "portfolio", $args );
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}

add_action( 'init', 'cptui_register_my_cpts_portfolio' );
```

- Rewrite slug "category" is used by default post category and that's why may be you are getting 404 error.

Comment: I replaced this code and set permalink settings to "Post Name", but still the same error. Maybe I have an error in my pagination? I added it on my post

Comment: im updated my post with taxonomy-portfolio_categories.php

Comment: I have test this code in my local server and worked perfectly. Might be there should be any plugin that is affecting to this. Try to change permalink link to default and change to again pretty links.